# Filter function for nested lists in dr racket

Tags: racket

I am looking for a function that does what "filter" is used for, but without using filter. On top, it should also filter nested lists.
E. g. list ( 1 2 (list 3 'a 'b) 3 4) should return list (1 2 (list 3) 3 4).

I already have the function to filter. My thought is, that I have to distinguish in the beginning of the function, if first lst is a list itself.

What I got so far is:

```
     (define (my-filter pred lst)
     (cond ((null? lst) null)  ;;(after this I would try to test if it is a list itself, but I am not sure how)
    ((pred (first lst))
     (cons (first lst) (my-filter pred (rest lst))))
     (else (my-filter pred (rest lst)))))
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`list?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=list%3F#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list~3f%29%29)?

Comment: No, I don´t think so. The function should filter the given list. E.g. return only the numbers in the list.

Comment: You wrote in a code comment: "_...I would try to test if it is a list itself, but I am not sure how._" The `list?` predicate is how you tell if an element of `lst` is itself a list.

Comment: Oh yes, the list

Answer (score 0):

As it has been said in the comments, a possible solution is:

```
(define (my-filter pred lst)
  (cond [(null? lst) null]
        [(list? (first lst)) (cons (my-filter pred (first lst))
                                   (my-filter pred (rest lst)))]
        [else (if (pred (first lst))
                  (cons (first lst) (my-filter pred (rest lst)))
                  (my-filter pred (rest lst)))]))
```

**Example**

```
> (my-filter number? '(1 a 2 (3 (b 4) c) 5 6 d 7))
'(1 2 (3 (4)) 5 6 7)

> (my-filter (lambda (x) (not (number? x))) '(1 a 2 (3 (b 4) c) 5 6 d 7))
'(a ((b) c) d)
```